# Karate - Database testing - getting timestamp displayed as nano

Tags: karate

I am trying to run some basic database tests using Karate and Spring JDBC ( as mentioned in DBUtils class in Demo Project).

Here is what I am doing:

```
 Background:
    # Read url/username/pwd and provide it to the class
    * def config = read('env_file.json')
    * def DbUtils = Java.type('DbConnection')
    * def db = new DbUtils(config)

 Scenario: Validate the modd_ts is present in lob table

    * def createdTs = db.readRows('SELECT crtd_ts FROM tableA ')
    * print createdTs
```

Here is what it returns:

```
com.intuit.karate - [print] [{"crtd_ts":{"nanos":0}},{"crtd_ts":{"nanos":0}}
```

Not sure why it should return timestamp as "nanos":0 , seems a bug to me . Please confirm and I will open one in github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with Karate it is the implementation of `DbUtils`. It is up to you to write something that is right for your environment and database etc. Remember this is just part of the `karate-demo` as an example.